# Xamarin forms SignalR Notifications background service when app is closed

Tags: xamarin.forms, shiny, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, signalr

I'm building a Xamarin Forms App that uses SignalR to notify a user when there's a new post. I am currently using the LocalNotication Plugin, It works great when the App is in the background using a simulator. However, when  I kill the App(Swipe up) on the simulator, the SignalR disconnects, and I don't get Notifications anymore. How can I achieve something similar to WhatsApp and Instagram, basically being able to receive notifications even when the App is dead? I was thinking of Shiny 2.0 but not sure if I can receive notifications when App is not running.

Comment: I don't think its possible with SignalR, which requires an active connection. You will have to use native OS feature and send notification from Firebase cloud messaging for example. I have not used `Shiny` though from documentation it looks like it should be possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm just curious as to how WhatsApp does it